# Leer archivo txt en python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Tengo un archivo de texto txt que en cada linea tiene numeros separados por coma.
Vendría a ser una cosa así:

```
1,2,3,4,6
21,611,31,66,1
3,63,13,7,8,12,1
```

Etc.

Lo que quiero hacer es almacenar en una lista cada uno de los valores. En principio estoy separando las lineas en strings. El problema es que no puedo convertirlo a int porque tienen comas y la cantidad de numeros por cada linea es variable, entonces no puedo saber con exactitud donde va a estar la coma.
Hay algún metodo para poder transformar  cada uno de los elementos en números?.
Tengo que sacar un promedio de los números por cada linea.

```
    file=open("archivo.txt","w")
    for linea in archivo.readlines():
        print(linea)
```

Comment: puedes hacer linea.split(','), eso te separará el texto separado por comas en una lista o tupla que contendrá los numeros de manera independiente, asi podrás convertirlos a int.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
with open("leer.txt", "r") as datos:
    valores = []
    for linea in datos:
        valores.append([int(x) for x in linea.strip().split(",")])
    print(valores)
```

Abrimos el archivo a leer y usamos un `for linea in datos` para ir obteniendo una nueva línea en cada iteración.

A la línea en cuestión le eliminamos el '\n' al final usando `strip` y luego dividimos la línea por las comas usando `split`.

`split` devuelve una lista de caracteres, que convertimos a valores numéricos usando `int`.

*Archivo leer.txt*

```
1,2,3,4,6
21,611,31,66,1
3,63,13,7,8,12,1
```

El resultado es:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [21, 611, 31, 66, 1], [3, 63, 13, 7, 8, 12, 1]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: cadena.strip() no solo borra saltos de linea, también borra (si están) los espacios alrededor de la cadena.

Comment: @DanteS. No sólo los espacios, sino todos los white-spaces, que incluyen \t, \r, \f ...

Comment: mirá, ya aprendí algo nuevo! Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para poder realizar el código utilice dos métodos :

- `file.readlines()` : Para leer un archivo de texto en una lista
- `str.split()` : Para dividir un archivo de texto en una lista

Primero:

```
mi_archivo = open("archivo.txt", "r")
```

En este código vamos almacenar toda la información que esta en el archivo archivo.txt en la variable `mi_archivo`.
Después:

```
lista_aux = mi_archivo.readlines()
count = 0
```

Primero en mi variable `lista_aux` voy almacenar el archivo de texto en una lista
Después declaro la variable `count` que va a tener la función de contar la cantidad de veces que se va a tener una fila en la lista.
Después:

```
for line in lista_aux :
  count = 0
  sum_number = 0
```

Recorremos la `lista_aux` en cada fila mediante la variable line.
declaramos la variable `sum_number` donde almacenare la suma de los números de cada fila.

```
for i in line.split(','):
    count = count+1
    sum_number += int(i)
  print("promedio: {}".format(sum_number / count))
```

En este código vamos a recorrer (i) por cada fila que se almacena en la variable line pero `line.split(','):`  acá estamos separando cuando encuentre una coma (,) en cada fila y así se obtendrá de esto 1,2,3,4,5 -> '1', '2', '3', '4', '6' .
Después en el `count = count+1` se ira incrementando por cada elemento de la fila y así se podrá obtener la cantidad de elementos que hay en cada fila, para después usarlo como denominador para sacar el promedio.
En `sum_number += int(i)` en la variable `sum_number` se almacenara toda la suma de los números que están en su fila respectiva.
Para terminar después de finalizar de recorrer cada fila obtenemos su promedio mediante `print("promedio: {}".format(sum_number / count))` y obtenemos un resultado de un promedio por cada fila .

```
promedio: 3.2
promedio: 146.0
promedio: 15.285714285714286
```